# Order WordPress widgets in Bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

I know there are issues related to these and I have achieved something that works fairly well.

But I do not know how to make that in the mobile version, the widgets are placed at the end of the entire web.

This is how my structure looks in desktop mode.
[image]

And so it looks in mobile mode.
[image]

The idea is that the widget area be located at the end of the whole page.
Keep in mind that I'm implementing this in a **Wordpress theme** so according to the code I'm going to put next, I was going to put the call to the "sidebar" in a column.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-7 order-2 order-md-1">
        <div class="col">
          Playlist
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 order-1 order-md-2">
      <div class="col">
        Player
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Widget
        <!-- Here would go the call to the sidebar of Wordpress. -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
```

Update:
This is how I hope it looks in the mobile version.
[image]

Here an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/k0hmwgyq/

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: I just updated the question by putting a reference image of how I would like it to be to see the page in the mobile version.

Comment: You cannot put Playlist under the Player with the layout you provided. You need to separate the Widget area from a common parent where a Player is located.

Comment: @Kokox You can't to move the order with inside child column to next parent . All column should be inside `row` without any parent col.

Refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#order-classes